# Подключение vk sdk к проекту

Tags: android, вконтакте

Выполнял пошагово все инструкции с офф. сайта вк по подключению библиотеки vk sdk, но возникла ошибка.

1. скопировал папку вк в директорию проекта app (пробовал в этой директории создавать отдельную папку libs)
2. В основном файле проекта build.gradle подключил библиотеку include ':vksdk_library',':app', проект успешно сихнронизировался
3. Далее, при подключении в файле build.gradle непосредственно в директории проекта app следующей строки compile project(':vksdk_library') при синхронизации выводится сообщение: "Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found."

Где я сделал что-то не так?

Comment: "скопировал папку вк в директорию проекта app (пробовал в этой директории создавать отдельную папку libs)" -не совсем понятно, зачем вы пытались создать папку libs? Папка с сдк vksdk_library точно в корне проекта лежит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем усложнять себе жизнь?

1. Выделяешь свой проект, жмёшь F4.
2. Сверху жмешь зеленый плюсик New module.
3. После чего выбираешь Import Gradle Project.
4. Прописываешь путь к VK SDK.
5. Profit.